# Execute Power Shell Script upon starting a Browser Profile

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, browser, brave

For people familiar with Shell Scripts this should be a rather simple question, but I never made any useful Shell Script, so bear with me as a beginner.

I want to write a log when my (Brave) Browser opens a certain profile, say "Work", and write a log when it closes again.

I found a useful [tutorial](https://woshub.com/write-output-log-files-powershell/) which suggests basically this code:

```
$Logfile = "..."
function WriteLog
{
Param ([string]$LogString)
$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
$LogMessage = "$Stamp $LogString"
Add-content $LogFile -value $LogMessage
}

WriteLog "Started Process"
```

I would just make two scripts, one for starting and one for ending. But how would I make them execute as soon as I open my Browser Profile?
(Also: Will they end automatically, or will they clutter my working memory?)

My guess is that I will have to find the right windows process and somehow bind the execution of the script to starting this process. I am a little lost as to how to do that...

Comment: Does Brave offer you some callback you can use for registering you script? Otherwise I don't see a possibility except changing  Brave itself. I think a similar question has been discussed [here](https://community.brave.com/t/how-to-edit-the-source-code-of-brave-browser/400112).